# ggplot2 plotting alternate rows from 2 columns

Tags: r, sequence

I have a dataframe with 3 columns "ID", "on.tank", "on.mains". the data looks like:

ID: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 ( sequentially) on.tank: 25,0,10,0,43,0,5 on.mains: 0,12,0,11,0,2,0
so columns 2 and 3 alternate between zero and a value, where when one is a zero the other has a value alternately.

I want to create one column that interleaves each value alternately and a second column which will be a factor on.main, on.tank, on.main, etc alternating as it represents days on tank, then days on mains, then days on tank, etc, etc alternately.

I tried using melt but it doesn't give me alternating it stacks the data so I get on.tank, on.tank, on.tank etc for 2000 rows and then on.mains, on.mains etc

```
> dput(head(data))
structure(list(ID = 1:6, on.tank = c(0, 56, 0, 1, 0, 97), on.main = c(-1, 
0, -9, 0, -18, 0)), .Names = c("ID", "on.tank", "on.main"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Better to add sample data using `dput(mydata)` and some sample code. Cheers!

Comment: No sample code as end of a very long process including modelling in Vensim and R. this is the result but I just can't workout how to get alternating rows to one column and a second wth the on.tank, on.main  as factors?

Comment: sweet jesus, maybe next time use `dput(head(data))` :P

Comment: it would be perfect if `melt` could work by alternating rows instea dof stacking colums

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your data:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=1:7,
             on.tank=c( 25,0,10,0,43,0,5),
             on.mains=c(0,12,0,11,0,2,0))
```

Using base R:

```
df$On.which <- ifelse(df$on.tank > df$on.mains, "on.tank", "on.mains")
```

This will work unless any of your values are negative. If you have negative values use:

```
df$On.which <- ifelse(df$on.mains==0, "on.tank", "on.mains")
```

Does this do what you need? If you remove the quotes you can also use this method to get the values of the columns merged into 1.

Comment: That works. just had to reference the columns in df$columnname format

Comment: Oh yeah, totally forgot to add that :P

Comment: editted now. feel free to accept as answer if this fixed your issue